# Removing lines from powershell txt file

Tags: powershell

I'm having to simulate killing of task from process list. I get process list, send it to the text file process.txt and then have user input the task they want to kill. My main problem, is I have to do this in a loop. But unless I change the out-file to process2.txt the whole file is deleted. So when I get to the loop part where I ask them to keep killing process until they abort, I'd end up with a lot of files. Is there anyway to keep the same file and just delete the line they enter?

```powershell
function KillTask {
    get-process | out-file "D:\process.txt"
    Get-Content -Path D:\process.txt
    $Killtask = Read-Host -Prompt "What task would you like to kill"
    get-content D:\process.txt | select-string -AllMatches $killtask -  notmatch |         Out-File D:\process2.txt -force
    Get-Content -Path D:\process2.txt
    }
```

Comment: do you need to work with files? Can't you just store the information in a variable? or do you need those files for further use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're recursively calling this function, just return your matched process:

```
function KillTask {
   get-process | out-file "D:\process.txt"
   $Killtask = Read-Host -Prompt "What task would you like to kill"
   get-content D:\process.txt | select-string -AllMatches $killtask
}

Do {
   $process = KillTask
   # do stuff with the process
} While ($process)
```

I'm not sure why process.txt or process2.txt are ever created to store information. As SimonS mentioned, can't this information be stored in variables?